# sudo chmod 755 /dev/sda7 -R simply returns a new command prompt line?

Tags: sudo, directory, partitioning, chmod, editing

I am logged into my computer through the guest account, because i am unable to login through the master/admin. Account via user interface. (simply a blank, blue screen appears upon login . So i'm using ctrl+alt+f1 to access the master account via terminal.

My goal is to clean up whatever is inside /dev/sda7, as it's 100% used.

I've tried:

"ls -a /dev/sda7" hoping that this would return a list of sub-directories & files within /dev/sda7, but all that is returned is:

"/dev/sda7" (in the color yellow).

Since I can't seem to return a list of sub-directories & files on the partition, I tried:

"sudo chmod 755 /dev/sda7 -r" in hopes of editing the contents of the directory. What's returned in this case is an immediate, new command line prompt. It's as if it's recognized that i've typed something, and maybe it did something in the background, or maybe there's an error, or maybe it just wants more input from me.

As a last resort, I've tried removing a different directory:

"sudo rm -rf /dev/sda6"

Again, I was returned to a new command line prompt.

How can I view the contents of directories and files found on /dev/sda7?

How can I remove them?

Keep in mind, i'm technically logged into an interface via guest account, but have successfully logged into master/admin account via terminal.

Thanks, all.

---

As Instructed:

```
d@d-Satellite-C655  : ls -l /dev/sda6 /dev/sda7
Brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 6 Sep 11 21  : /dev/sda6
Brw-rw---- 1 rood disk 8, 7 Sep 11 21  : /dev/sda7
```

Note: bold text denotes text that was returned as yellow, instead of the standard grey on black.

Comment: `/dev` entries are representations of devices themselves, *not* folders containing files located on the device. So the first order of business should be to figure out what you have done to your system by removing and changing permissions on these device nodes, and reversing it. Then the original problem regarding free space can be tackled. What's the output of `ls -l /dev/sda6 /dev/sda7`? (Please [edit] your question to include it.) Also, were you logged in as a guest for *all* the `rm ...` and `chmod ...` commands? They should fail as guest, even with sudo (but you'd see an error message).

Comment: Yes, i was logged into the computer interface as guest for all commands.

However, after logging into the computer interface as guest, i opened a TTY1 console and logged in with the administrator account, which gave me permission previously denied to guest.

I now believe commands ran successfully when logged into the admin. account via tty1 console, as i didn't receive error messages i had received when running the same commands (that had received errors) as guest.

All of my "i"s are left lowercase to display humility? All the other pronouns are lowercase.Am i more important than you or him?

Comment: 1- The UNIX way is for commands to just return silently if they succeeded. The rationale is that it's a simple task so confirmation is not needed. An explanation *will* be provided if there's an error. If you need information of what the command is doing, most commands support a `-v` switch (`chmod -v ...`). 2- Your rationale for keeping the pronoun 'I' lowercase is commendable, but I would advise you to capitalize it, as otherwise it is grammatically incorrect (http://www.towson.edu/ows/capitalization_rules.htm).

Comment: I'm learning that the commands i'm typing are, in fact, running, as there are no errors. But when they're apparently the sorts of commands that return a list of results in text, when i run them, they produce no text. Which, in this case, could mean that where there once were directories, there now are none.

Thanks for the info. on the -v modifier/switch. This is brand new to me!

Answer (score 1):

***Never ever ever delete stuff unless you are SURE that it's okay to delete it!***

In your case, you are looking for the `mount` command. `/dev/sda7` is a block file, not a directory.

To see the files available on hard drive 1, sector 7, run this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
```

All of the files on /dev/sda7 will be in the /mnt folder on your hard drive, and you can see them by running `sudo ls /mnt`

Also, by playing with permissions and deleting stuff in `/dev`, you might have really messed up your system. Make sure everything works. Try rebooting (It usually fixes `/dev` stuffs). If that fails, reinstall!

---

Also, many UNIX tools (especially `chmod`, `rm` and many other core utils) only output in the  case of a failure.

Comment: d@d-Satellite-C655:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt  
[sudo] password for d:  

[I guess this means i successfully deleted it! And now i know that's a bad thing. Odear.]

Comment: @slack Nope. Not a bad thing!! That means your system is just asking for the password to mount the drive. Mounting a drive needs root permissions.

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to return a list of files, though? Instead, it asked me for my password, and returned no list at all. I still remain at a loss on what command to run, to make /dev/sda7 (if it even exists anymore) less than 100% used. Any suggestions?

Comment: @slack I edited my post. Enter your password, and then run `ls /mnt` as the root user.

Comment: Hmm. Running ls /mnt didn't return any results, but took me to the next command line prompt, so i guess it ran. But then i did it again, and typoed "ls / mnt" (note space) and that showed me a bunch of familiar folders for my master/admin login. That's the same as "ls /". Maybe i should snoop around and edit/remove some familiar files? I also noticed that the tmp folder was highlighted in green, and "PlayOnLinux's virtual drive" (<--possible slight misquote) was in...aqua text. Not sure what the fancy colors mean. ...or how to snoop into PlayOnLinux junk. What say ye?

Comment: Pls no break further. Run `sudo ls /mnt` (note the no space)

Comment: Again, no text returned from transaction.

d@d-Satellite-C655:~$ sudo ls /mnt  
[sudo] password for d:  
d@d-Satellite-C655:~$

Comment: Downvote? Why??

Comment: i didn't do it! (and i kinda wonder why, myself.) thanks again, brah!

Comment: @slack Never blamed you. It's just customary to explain a downvote. This downvoter didn't. :(